# Getting wrong week number in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I am trying to get week Number in iPhone.  I am using this piece of code

```
NSNumber* getWeek() {
    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"w.ee"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
    NSNumberFormatter *weekNumber = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [weekNumber setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber *week = [weekNumber numberFromString:dateString];
    [weekNumber release];
    return week;
 }
```

However, I have difference result, at simulator is ok, but when I ran in iPhone this got me "0"
IOS 5.0.1

Any helps?

Comment: this code is working perfectly on my real device. I think your real problem is not inside this method...

Comment: Have you checked the date set on your iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a string for the week number is not the best way to get to this kind of information. `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` have been designed specifically for this kind of calculation:

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:currDate];
NSLog(@"%d %d", components.weekOfYear, components.weekday);
```

You can specify a list of components in the calendar call (line 3) as seen in the example note that only the specified components are guaranteed to be filled in the `NSDateComponents` object.

Comment: Make sure you take care of possible timezone issues, too, if the app will be used world wide!